# ConcurrentModificationException on removing Overlay from MapView's overlayList

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to search for a custom ItemizedOverlay that contains certain data...
I keep getting a ConcurrentModificationException on the for-loop when i'm trying to run through all the overlays of my MapView.

I hope somebody knows the answer to this problem...

here's the code:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Activityresult", "voor ok");
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6(), touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6());
        Car car = data.getExtras().getParcelable("car");
        PinpointItem pinpoint = new PinpointItem(point, car, DropHostCarActivity.this);
        CustomPinpointOverlay custom = new CustomPinpointOverlay(d, DropHostCarActivity.this);
        custom.insertPinpoint(pinpoint);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        if (mapOverlays.size() > 1) {
            removeSameCar(mapOverlays,car);
        }
        overlayList.add(custom);
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
}

private void removeSameCar(List<Overlay> mapOverlays, Car car) {
    for(Overlay overlay: mapOverlays){
        if(overlay instanceof CustomPinpointOverlay && 
                ((CustomPinpointOverlay) overlay).getItem(0).getCar().getNumberPlate().equals(car.getNumberPlate())){
            overlayList.remove(overlay);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah okay, I've now made a copy of the MapView's OverlayList and used this to put in the for loop. This solved the initial problem. Only now, other overlays seem to have been removed as well... i'll have to search into that aswell, thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: You can remove an item from a list while iterating, provided you use an iterator to iterate, and use the iterator's remove() method to remove the item. This avoids an unnecessary copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only modify the list with the method remove of the Iterator while you are iterating, if the List implementation supports it. You need to use the iterator explicitly:

```
private void removeSameCar(List<Overlay> mapOverlays, Car car) {
    Iterator<Overlay> it = mapOverlays.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Overlay overlay = it.next();
        if(overlay instanceof CustomPinpointOverlay && 
                ((CustomPinpointOverlay) overlay).getItem(0).getCar().getNumberPlate().equals(car.getNumberPlate())){
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```